# webapp2 How to remove Cache-Control: no-cache from response header?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, internet-explorer-8, blobstore, webapp2

I'm having trouble serving an appengine blobstore over HTTPS, specifically with IE 8 & IE 7 browsers, as the browser just does not like to serve downloadable contents over https.
According to a microsoft article, it's because of the **Cache-Control: no-cache** header.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/02/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx

The solution proposed in the article is to remove the Cache-Control: no-cache header from the response.
However, it seems that webapp2 automatically adds this header even after I tried setting it to something else.

According to the source code, it seems to be added to every response 
http://code.google.com/p/webapp-improved/source/browse/webapp2.py#362

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Constructs a response with the default settings."""
        super(Response, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
```

Is there a way to override this behavior?

This is what I tried to do when building my response, but still the 'Cache-Control: no-cache' would still be there once the response is rendered.

```
self.response.headers['Pragma'] = 'cache-control'
self.response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'private'
self.response.cache_control.no_cache = None
self.response.cache_control.public = False
self.response.cache_control.max_age = 1
```

Comment: I found an answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680530/gae-blobstore-issue-download-fails-in-internet-explorer-8

Answer (score 0):

I do not use webapp2 in the download handler itself. It looks like this:

```
class DynServe(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):

    def get(self, resource):                                       

        (key, _, _) = resource.rpartition('.')
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(key)     
        self.send_blob(blob_info, save_as=True)    


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
                          [
                           ('/dynserve/([^/]+)?', DynServe),
                          ], debug=True)
def main():
    app.run()
```

To serve a pdf like: /dynserve/{{ blob-key }}.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but still I'm getting an error when serving the data over HTTPS in IE8/IE7. It works for other browsers (IE9, Chrome, Firefox).

Comment: Strange. I checked it with IE9 in development mode for IE7 and in works fine. It receives a Cache-Control: no-cache. I checked it with this PDF: http://www.energiekantoor.nl/dynserve/AMIfv95UXvxIPFeaZJtivKSpbrY8Xb_HaXQqJ3SHm9_o1MGWmz7alBYqExJ2qNPqSzjb-gKf1gkF2_lh1cC4v2lrMp6-aQq4aErh_UwxnM13V9mtWJuyYOQCzDQtWfFPWowRkzU2S9RxKZgAenoNkIqODdXRsYHttQ.pdf

Comment: Sorry. The link above is not using https.

Comment: I can not give you a https link example. It is not public. But https serving works for me with IE9 in development mode for IE7.